# How to transfer data from element to a delegate event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, delegates

I wanted to retrieve the element data from the delegate onclick event handler, and got it working, but suddenly I run into some problems.

Finally I isolated the issue: It seems that the data attached to the element
is being deleted when the element is removed from the DOM. And this might happen
before the delegate onclick event handler is called.

Since sometimes I would have an click event handler which would remove the element before the delegated handler could run.

Consider this document:

```
<div id='content'>
    <a href="#pp" class='remove'>Will be removed ( data is lost )</a>
    <a href="#pp">Will stay ( works )</a>
</div>
```

and this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').data("keep", {
        content: 'want to see at delegate click envent'
    });
    $('a').click(function () {
        var data = $(this).data("keep"),
            data_to_show = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : 'Real Gone!!';
        alert("click: " + data_to_show);
        if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $('#content').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
        var data = $(this).data("keep"),
            data_to_show = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : 'Real Gone!!';
        alert("delegate: " + data_to_show);
    });
});
```

you can play with it at: http://jsfiddle.net/s47c5/4/

I could post-pone the removal of the element, wrapping it into a timeout...

```
    if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {
        setTimeout ( function () { 
            $(this).remove()
        }, 10 );
    }
```

and it works, but somehow this creeps me out!

So the question is:

How could I properly transfer data from the item to be deleted so it reaches the delegated event handler?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').data("keep", {
        content: 'want to see at delegate click envent'
    });
    $('a').click(function () {
        var data = $(this).data("keep"),
            data_to_show = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : 'Real Gone!!';
        alert("click: " + data_to_show);

    });
    $('#content').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
        var data = $(this).data("keep"),
        data_to_show = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : 'Real Gone!!';
        alert("delegate: Before removing >" + data_to_show);
        if ($(this).hasClass('remove')) {
            $(this).remove();            
        }
        //After removing 
        data = $(this).data("keep");
        data_to_show = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : 'Real Gone!!';
        alert("delegate: After removing >" + data_to_show);
    });
});
```

See I have made changes in JS fiddle:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/s47c5/10/)

Comment: @user2043273 see I have added answer it is working on givem JSfiddle.

Comment: yeap, your solution is basically delaying the removal of the item as with the setTimeout(), and it is less creepy than my workaround, however i am not looking for a way to keep the item 'alive' any longer, but to transfer the data by some other means. maybe attaching the data to the event? ).

In fact, i am not under such control, since $(this).remove() is actually nested under some complex layers of code; It might even remove $('#content'), and not just the element.